# Vba If else (Basic)

Tags: vba, if-statement, basic

Would like to include a value to all my cells in column G if there are blank in column K, else no change.

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("K").Value, Criteria1:=" = " Then ActiveSheet.Range("G").Value = "Promo"

Else
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: your If statement, if using an Else, cannot have anything on the same line after the Then. You need ActiveSheet.Range("G").Value = "Promo"  on a new line before the Else.   If statement syntax I don't think uses the criteria argument as shown . It is If _yourTestCondition_ Then

Comment: At what row do you want to stop? Typically you stop at the first blank occurence...

Comment: approx 451 line exclude header.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test all the values you need to loop through the column. My example assumes the data doesn't have more than 100'000 lines and that you were testing for " = " to be included... addapt as needed.

```
Sub TestColumnK()

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Range("K100000").End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Value, "=") > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i).Value = "Promo"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @QHarr i realized it was prob not meant to be included... i removed it in an edit. but you are right : )

Comment: It is possible there is whitespace but I think just a note about it is probably advisable. Depending on their version you can also use .HasFormula.

Comment: Hi Rohrl77, I tried to used your code above but I cant see any changes. Do I have to make changes?

Comment: I would use the code following to filter the blank in column G. After which I need the IF code to fill up Column G if column K is blank and if column L have value.

<Code> Sub FilterRows()
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=" = "
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:=" = "
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:="<>"
End Sub <Code>